# "82635.080657" - secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb | Will not shut down

Tags: centos, files, fedora, filesystems, live-usb

I am shutting down from a Fedora34 and the shut down process has been halted at

```
[82635.080657] - secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
```

The cursor is not blinking but is showing.

Now before I shut down I was trying to find out what processes were using `/dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var` I found three PIDs that were using `/dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var`. `108146, 112141, 108059` I then `kill -SIGTERM 10846` I then rebooted and machine is now stuck at

```
[82635.080657] - secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
```

I'm thinking of removing the LiveUSB and booting into Emergency Mode and go from there. I am puzzled at how a LiveUSB is taking this long to boot down.  It must be related to the `kill -SIGTERM 10846` I did.

Comment: why would you need to shut down a LiveUSB distro ... pulling the plug is ok because the filesystem is in ram

Comment: Merci, edited question.